# Mvc Telerik grid cancel cell changes when input invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am facing a small problem regarding input validation in mvc telerik grid.
I have it set to batch editting and I'm modifing the cells in an InCell mode.
Now whenever a user enters an invalid value in one of the inputs(Telerik's comboboxes/autocompletes), I'd like to display a message that
the entered value is iligal(this far I've managed on my own).

In addition to the message I'd like to revert the cell's value to it's previus value before
the user input.

So far I've tried:

```
grid.CancelCell(this);
$('#grid .t-grid-edit-cell input[type="text"]').value or innerText = prevVal;
```

The closest so far was `e.newVal = e.oldVal`, although it sometimes throws me a wierd exception in the jquery scripts or displays the combobox's drop down.

All the validatios and things I've tried are from the grid's client event `OnSave()`

Answer (score 0):

It's same like what i searched before and I have solution for you.

On your `OnSave()` method has event like `OnSave(e)` and that 'e' carry all the elemnts and functions inside in my example after validation if not ok i can change that value to old value. Also you can use inspecter element log to look up what is inside 'e'

```
function onSave(e){
        if(!validation)
        {
           ///
        }
        else
        {
           e.cell.firstChild.value = "0"; // that is my edited cell 
        }
}
```